# How to check if a nonlinear system is stabilizable and detectable?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, stability-theory, linear-control, kalman-filter

If I have a linear system, I can check with the following procedure. Consider the linear system:

$$\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{u}$$
$$\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{u} $$

I can check if the unobservable and uncontrollable modes are detectable and stabilizable by looking at the eigenvalue decomposition i.e., $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{W} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{V}$ of the system.

I can check if $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{W}$ has any zero columns and if $\mathbf{V} \mathbf{B}$ has any zero rows. If so, the zero columns and zero rows correspond to the unobservable and uncontrollable modes. However, even if unobservable/uncontrollable, I can check if the eigenvalues are in the LHP (left hand plane), and if so, the modes are detectable/stabilizable respectively.

How can I check for nonlinear systems? I can linearize, but that requires some linearization point, and in that case, I will only be able to check if stabilizable/detectable about some point. Also, I don't know if that is even a valid approach for some specific point.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are only interested into stabilizability and detectability and not controllability and observability?

Comment: In general, stabilizability and detectability are weaker notions of controllability and observability. If a system is not observable/controllable, we can test and check for stabilizability/detectability.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Controllability/observability requires to drive/construct the states in *finite* time, while stability deals with the behavior in infinite time. C/O actually deals with the vector space spanning capability of the states for various input/output signals, which turn out to be depended on the system structure.

Comment: @obareey I don't undersand what you mean. If a system is stabilizable, the unstable states are controllable, and if a system is detectable, the unstable state are observable. Can you please explain?

Comment: This is true but it is not a definition. You can prove it by using the definitions (and for linear systems). What I wanted to say is *in principle* they are different things but *turned out to be* this way. Now come to think of it, I'm not entirely sure this statement holds for nonlinear systems in general, maybe locally.

Comment: @obareey This is the definition provided in "Optimal State Estimation" by Dan Simon. Also, if you have any more insight (or a reference) regarding stabilizbility/detectability for nonlinear system. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be interested in this article: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/553690. From the abstract "It is well known that, contrary to the linear case, local controllability does not necessarily imply stabilizability." Also it gives good intuition in the introduction. The original paper that makes it "well-known": http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=1A8E004F30FF330D1B9C093917ADD4C2?doi=10.1.1.324.9912&rep=rep1&type=pdf